# Is it possible to make non fPIC dylib in Mac?

Tags: macos, gcc, darwin

During test of my software on Mac, I want to check whether it works fine with fPIC and non-fPIC dylibs.

As I can see in some internet references that, -fPIC is a default option for gcc in Mac OSX. so, whether I use it or not during compilation, I always get position independent dynamic library.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/mac/ch05_03.htm
(One difference between Darwin and many other Unix systems is that no position-independent code (PIC) flag is needed, since it is the default for Darwin.)

So, my questions are :

(1) Is it possible to create non position independent dylib in Mac (with gcc)?

(2) How to check whether a dylib is position independent or non position independent?

Thanks,

Comment: Even if it was possible, it is probably not advisable to make a non-PIC dynamic library.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What would be the benefit?

Comment: I haven't much worked on dynamic libraries, and I understand that PIC dynamic libraries are of more use than non PIC. But my software  does some work on dylibs to calculate their checksums to protect libraries from hacking. so I want  to make sure whether the library is PIC or noPIC my software will work fine.